# meteor shell using .load

Tags: shell, meteor

Meteor newbie here. When I start `meteor shell` and open the help menu, one of the command is `.load`, but I don't know how to use this and wasn't able to find documentation. I have a `file.js` in the root of the project directory.  Here's what I have tried so far:

```
# in a meteor shell
> .load
Failed to load:
> .load ./file.js
Failed to load:./file.js
> .load file.js
Failed to load:file.js
> .load("./file.js")
Invalid REPL keyword
```

An example usage would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should give the full path of the file to the `.load` command.

**Mac solution**

First Open the terminal and [drag the file into the terminal](http://osxdaily.com/2009/11/23/copy-a-files-path-to-the-terminal-by-dragging-and-dropping/), you should get something like this.

```
/Users/yourName/Desktop/helper/test.js
```

Now with that path just run.

```
meteor shell
.load /Users/yourName/Desktop/helper/test.js
```

**Linux solution**

use [readlink](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readlink.1.html)

```
readlink -f file.txt //copy the path and do the same meteor shell .load given path
```

**Windows Solution**

Right click on the file and `copy as Path`, here is an [image example](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/copy-path-of-a-file-to-the-clipboard-in-windows-vista/).
and repeat the same like on the mac and linux solutions.

Here is my output of an example.

```
> .load /Users/Ethaan/Desktop/helper/test.js
> console.log("Test") //i have this on a single file.
>
```